# Why are there two different formulas for $R^2$?

Tags: regression, correlation, r-squared

Whereby one method is to square the $r$ (hence $r^2$) or the correlation coefficient, and the other method is 1 - (Sum of Squared Errors (from the regression line) / Sum of Squared Errors (from the mean y), i.e. 
$$R^2=1-\frac{\text{SSE}}{\text{SST}}$$

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 2):

In [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression), we have $\hat{y_i}=\hat{\beta}x_i+\hat{\alpha}$, where 
$$\hat{\beta}={{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}\over {\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}},\ \ \ \hat{\alpha}=\bar{y}-\hat{\beta}\bar{x}\rightarrow \hat{y}_i-\bar{y}=\hat{\beta}(x_i-\bar{x})$$
Substituting this into the formula of coefficient of determination:
$$\begin{align}R^2&=\frac{SSR}{SST}=\frac{\sum (\hat{y_i}-\bar{y})^2}{\sum (y_i-\bar{y})^2}=\hat{\beta}^2\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2}{\sum (y_i-\bar{y})^2}\\&=\left({{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}\over {\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}\right)^2\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2}{\sum (y_i-\bar{y})^2}\\&=\left(\underbrace{{{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}\over {\sqrt{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2\sum (y_i-\bar{y})^2}}}}_{R=\text{correlation coef.}}\right)^2\end{align}$$